# Delphi 11 Define String Type ( ) vs [ ]

Tags: delphi, pascal

I'm using Delphi 11 to build TurboPower BTree Filer, which is supposed to support Delphi up to 2006 version.   Since using newer version I have to convert Char to AnsiChar and String to AnsiString but this string type definition fails in Delphi 11:

```
const
  IsamFileNameLen = 64;

type
  IsamFileName = ansistring[IsamFileNameLen];
```

It doesn't like the square brackets, so I presume it wants  parentheses (), but it didn't like those either?

What is the problem?

Edit: If it's just "string" then it is okay but it's not what I need, I need ansistring ?

Thanks!

Comment: No, actually the correct type is `string[IsamFileNameLen] `. `ShortString` is a pre-existing alias for `string[255]`

Comment: Almost certainly you are going about the entire project wrongly.

Comment: Someone tried to port it to XE2, see this attempt: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837159/turbopower-b-tree-filer-and-delphi-xe2-anyone-done-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that `string` typically refers to `AnsiString`
before D2009, and to `UnicodeString` since D2009. But, only when used as a **dynamic long string** . When used as a **fixed-length short string**  instead, `string` still refers to an ANSI type. So, the correct declaration remains the same in all versions:

```
const
  IsamFileNameLen = 64;

type
  IsamFileName = string[IsamFileNameLen];
```

This is described in Delphi's documentation:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types_(Delphi)

> The Delphi language supports short-string types - in effect, subtypes of [`ShortString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ShortString) - whose maximum length is anywhere from 0 to 255 characters. These are denoted by **a bracketed numeral appended to the reserved word [`string`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.String)**. For example:
>
> ```
> var MyString: string[100];
> ```
>
> creates a variable called `MyString`, whose maximum length is 100 characters. This is equivalent to the declarations:
>
> ```
> type CString = string[100];
> var MyString: CString;
> ```

Comment: It looks like I should be using ShortString for all the other strings too since I'm converting this DOS pascal app to Delphi.   Somewhere it may reference index [0] for the length.  So it automatically knows if you use [] that the string is an ansistring or does it know it's a ShortString since [0] I guess is different.

Comment: The compiler knows the string type you are using. It treats `[]` depending on the real type.

Comment: My worry is if I use `ansistring` where they were using `string` for DOS version, they may have used [0] to get/set the length of the string since that how it was with that version.  Does `ansistring[0]` emulate a `shortstring[0]` for length information?

Comment: Oh nice, I see they did use [0] and the compiler picked it up and said `Element 0 inaccessible - use 'Length' or 'SetLength'` so I'll be able to do it either way, I think I'll stick with AnsiString and handle issues as compiler finds it.

Comment: "*My worry is if I use `ansistring` where they were using `string` for DOS version, they may have used `[0]` to get/set the length of the string*" - they would only have done that if `string` were `ShortString` not `AnsiString` (ie [`{$H-}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Long_strings_(Delphi)) in pre-2009 versions of Delphi). "*Does `ansistring[0]` emulate a `shortstring[0]` for length information?*" - no.